Use OPENPYXL to write notes (comments) to cells using row and column number
I have written code that opens an macro-enabled Excel template file (.xltm), writes a pandas dataframe to a specific location in that file, and saves the file as a regular macro-enabled workbook (.xlsm). Some cells of the dataframe contain strings while others contain dictionaries.
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(stemplatepath, keep_vba=True)
ws = wb['Health']
rows = dataframe_to_rows(dflower, index=False, header=False)
for r_idx, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
    for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            ws.cell(row=r_idx+10, column=c_idx, value=value['status'])
            if value['comment']:
                ws.cell(row=r_idx+10, column=c_idx).comment = value['comment'] # This line doesn't work
        else:
            ws.cell(row=r_idx+10, column=c_idx, value=value)
wb.template = False
wb.save(soutputpath)

The documentation only shows syntax for adding comments by address:
comment = Comment("Text", "Author")
ws["A1"].comment = comment

Is there a method for adding comments by row and column number so that I can keep it inside my for loop?

What you have will work for determining the cell co-ordinate but you're not adding the comment to the cell correctly per the doc;
Change
 ws.cell(row=r_idx+10, column=c_idx).comment = value['comment'] # This line doesn't work

to
 ws.cell(row=r_idx+10, column=c_idx).comment = Comment(value['comment'], "<author>")

or you can create a variable for the comment as shown
comment = Comment(value['comment'], "Author")

and apply that
 ws.cell(row=r_idx+10, column=c_idx).comment = comment

The important part being the value applied to the comment attribute of the cell is an Openpyxl Comment object which has a number of attributes and not a just string.
Also don't forget to import Comment from Openpyxl if you haven't already included it.
from openpyxl.comments import Comment

The second string value is supposed to be the Author for the comment and must be included.
Note; you can also include the sizing for the comment, height and width as integers;
ws.cell(row=r_idx+10, column=c_idx).comment = Comment(value['comment'], "<author>", 80, 40)

